# 7.0.100/NuGet.targets(396,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/src/WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj" was not found. [/src/MyMicroservice.sln]

Tags: asp.net, docker, microservices

#11 0.734 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/NuGet.targets(396,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/src/WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj" was not found. [/src/MyMicroservice.sln]

tried changing its location but it was no good

Comment: i have been trying to build a  microservice application but after solving multiple errors I faced this one. Despite the error saying it can't find the file, I can see it on my folder where it should be. any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.